# How to interpret Keras model.fit output?

Tags: keras

I've just started using Keras.  The sample I'm working on has a model and the following snippet is used to run the model

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelBinarizer
label_binarizer = LabelBinarizer()
y_one_hot = label_binarizer.fit_transform(y_train)

model.compile('adam', 'categorical_crossentropy', ['accuracy'])
history = model.fit(X_normalized, y_one_hot, nb_epoch=3, validation_split=0.2)
```

I get the following response:

```
Using TensorFlow backend. Train on 80 samples, validate on 20 samples Epoch 1/3

32/80 [===========>..................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 1.5831 - acc:
0.4062 80/80 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 1.3927 - acc:
0.4500 - val_loss: 0.7802 - val_acc: 0.8500 Epoch 2/3

32/80 [===========>..................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.9300 - acc:
0.7500 80/80 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 0.8490 - acc:
0.8000 - val_loss: 0.5772 - val_acc: 0.8500 Epoch 3/3

32/80 [===========>..................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.6397 - acc:
0.8750 64/80 [=======================>......] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.6867 - acc:
0.7969 80/80 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 0.6638 - acc:
0.8000 - val_loss: 0.4294 - val_acc: 0.8500
```

The [documentation](https://keras.io/models/model/) says that fit returns

> A History instance. Its history attribute contains all information
>   collected during training.

Does anyone know how to interpret the history instance?

For example, what does 32/80 mean?  I assume 80 is the number of samples but what is 32?  ETA: 0s ??

Answer (score 22):

ETA = Estimated Time of Arrival.

`80` is the size of your **training set**, `32/80` and `64/80` mean that your batch size is 32 and currently the first batch (or the second batch respectively) is being processed.

`loss` and `acc` refer to the current loss and accuracy **of the training set**.
At the end of each epoch your trained NN is evaluated against your **validation set**. This is what `val_loss` and `val_acc` refer to.

The history object returned by `model.fit()` is a simple class with some fields, e.g. a reference to the `model`, a `params` dict and, most importantly, a `history` dict. It stores the values of `loss` and `acc` (or any other used metric) at the end of each epoch. For 2 epochs it will look like this:

```
{
    'val_loss': [16.11809539794922, 14.12947562917035],
    'val_acc': [0.0, 0.0],
    'loss': [14.890108108520508, 12.088571548461914],
    'acc': [0.0, 0.25]
}
```

This comes in very handy if you want to [visualize](https://keras.io/visualization/) your training progress.

Note: if your validation loss/accuracy starts increasing while your training loss/accuracy is still decreasing, this is an indicator of overfitting.

Note 2: at the very end you should test your NN against some **test set** that is different from you training set and validation set and thus has never been touched during the training process.

Comment: Question: when batches are being processed, `loss` keep updating on. Now, tell me if the `loss` is evalauted over the `entire dataset` or just on the `batch`. TIA.

Comment: @chandresh as far as I know it's a running average loss, i.e. the loss of the entire dataset progressed so far.

Comment: Regarding the 80 value, it should be equivalent to the training data set size. However, I am getting a value of '4/4' in my output with keras in R. However, my training data set has a sample size of 113. Am I misinterpreting the second number after the dash?

Comment: 80 is not the size of the training set. It is actually the number of batches. So, the size of the training set is 80 * batch_size. If the batch_size is 64, then the size of training set is 80 * 64. The batch_size is not given in the output.

Comment: @ibilgen I haven't been using keras for about 2 years now, so I cannot tell how it is now. But back when I wrote this answer, 80 definitely was the training set size. Maybe they changed the output meanwhile to show the number of batches instead?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Thanks for the clarification. I deduced it from an example used Keras version 2.10

Answer (score 10):

`32` is your batch size. 32 is the default value that you can change in your fit function if you wish to do so.

After the first batch is trained Keras estimates the training duration (ETA: estimated time of arrival) of one epoch which is equivalent to one round of training with all your samples.

In addition to that you get the losses (the difference between prediction and true labels) and your metric (in your case the accuracy) for both the training and the validation samples.

Comment: do you what acc:0.4062 80/80 means too? acc = accuracy? 80/80 80 correct out of 80?  Wouldn't that mean acc = 1.0?  Is there a reference link to the meaning of the output anywhere?

Comment: `80/80` means "80 samples from a total of 80 samples" have been trained. Therefore the first entry that you see is `32/80` which says: "32 of a total of 80 samples". The accuracy in turn is calculated from the values that your network at this point predicts vs the actual values that you have provided in form of your labels.

Comment: Your question regarding the meaning of the output is kind of a broader question and I respectfully recommend that you look into one of the many courses that teach the basics, i.e. [this one](http://course.fast.ai/) from Jeremy Howard, which is very accessible.

Comment: @petezurick thanks!  However, I'm not looking for the meaning of accuracy etc. rather just what the abbreviations mean, (coming from Tensorflow background).  I would have thought there would be a page explaining what a history output is.  Thanks for the link!

Comment: @SeanJ I see. Sorry for the misunderstanding. Than [this might be of help](https://machinelearningmastery.com/display-deep-learning-model-training-history-in-keras/).

Comment: @SeanJ Please remember to accept the answer if it has helped so that others can see that your question is solved. Thanks.

Comment: answer is good but incomplete.  No reference and  val_loss:  val_acc not described...

Comment: 80 is the number of batches. So the actual size of training set is 80 x batch_size.