# keras, how to interpret the output(loss, acc calculated on what data) of each batch in each epoch during training

Tags: keras, output

I understand there is a similar question "[How to interpret Keras model.fit output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46218407/how-to-interpret-keras-model-fit-output?answertab=votes#tab-top)" , but my question is more specific, I am wondering how the loss and acc output of each batch inside one epoch are calculated?

- is it calculated upon the validation set?
- or on the trained samples so far in each epoch?(I think its this one )
- or anything else?

below is a sample output during my training:

```
Epoch x/20:
...
54320/55200 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 1.2083 - acc: 0.9554
54440/55200 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 1.2083 - acc: 0.9554
54560/55200 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 1.2083 - acc: 0.9555
...
```

my configuration:

```
model.fit(x_train, y_train,
          batch_size=10,
          epochs=20,
          verbose=1,
          validation_split=0.08)
```

Thank  you!

Answer (score 1):

The values are:

- loss - **training data**, calculated **every batch**
- acc - **training data**, calculated **every batch**
- val_loss - **test data**, calculated **every epoch**
- val_acc - **test data**, calculated **every epoch**

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: sorry not being accurate, the sample output is for each batch in one epoch.after each epoch, there do have these 4 number, which are of no doubt. And it does reach the end, just not in the sample above, I have edited it.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. So that means it calculates the accuracy of all the seen samples so far during the epoch after each batch? And what's for the loss?