# Understanding Keras history object

Tags: python, keras

Note: There is one similar question to the one I asked here and it can be found here

[How to interpret Keras model.fit output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46218407/how-to-interpret-keras-model-fit-output)

My question is different as different kind of results are there in both the questions. The important this is that the question referred above has not been answered as it has not been accepted. So kindly answer my question.

I am new to Keras and I have just created a CNN. I want to understand what these results are depicting. I know that the history object stores loss and accuracy for both training set as well as validation set but here I have some queries in regard to following obtained results:

[image: Keras History object output]

1. Under epoch 14 why there are only 2 statements whereas in epoch 15, there are 6 statements. Why?
2. I am able to understand the statements under epoch 14 but I am not able to understand the statements under epoch 15 such as:

   (a). What is the final loss, acc, val_loss and val_acc of the model?

   Is it displayed in the first statement under the epoch 15 such as loss:0.6221 acc:0.6481 val_loss:0.6753 val_acc:0.6040.

   (b)What does the other lines below it indicate such as these:

   [image]

   What is 0.64923265/8000. Is it the accuracy on the training set using all 8000 
   images of the training set?
   Why only training results are shown in these statements. What about validation 
   results here?

   Is there any significance to arrows shown such as a long arrow or a short 
   arrow?

Please explain. Thank you.

Comment: I think that the arrows are just indicators of the progress and there should be only one, but your terminal emulator is not rendering it properly.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. As far as the significance of arrows is concerned you are right. I tried the same code on a different machine and it also shows multiple arrows along with outputs. So I think my terminal emulator is working fine! What about other queries. Can you answer please?

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51058604/8250094), I think most answers you seek are there. Also, I am pretty sure I have seen the output being properly displayed on one line (not multiple lines with different lengths), but most terminal emulators I use can't handle it properly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to interpret Keras model.fit output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46218407/how-to-interpret-keras-model-fit-output)

Comment: Yes it is similar to the one referred by you but the results are different. Also the one you are referring to has not been accepted as an answer as it is incomplete! Can you suggest how can i get answer to it?